# very magic regex that will allow me to replace these images?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using vim daily for manipulating text and to write code. However, every time I have to perform any substitution, or do any kind of regex work, it drives me crazy, and I have to switch to sublime. I'd like to know, what's the correct way of turning this:

```
<img src="whatever.png"/>
<img src="x.png"/>
```

into

```
<img src="<%= image_path("whatever.png") %>"/>
<img src="<%= image_path("x.png") %>"/>
```

In sublime, I can use this as the regex for search: `src="(.*?.png)"` and this as the regex for substitution: `src="<%= asset_path("\1") %>"`. In vim, if I do this: `:%s/\vsrc="(.*?.png)/src="<%= asset_path("\1") %>"/g` I get:

```
E62: Nested ?
E476: Invalid command
```

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @nhahtdh stated Vim's dialect of regex uses `\{-}` as the non-greedy quantifier. If you use the very magic flag it is just `{-}`. So your command turns into:

```
:%s/\vsrc="(.{-}.png)/src="<%= asset_path("\1") %>"/g
```

However you didn't escape the `.` in `.png` so:

```
:%s/\vsrc="(.{-}\.png)/src="<%= asset_path("\1") %>"/g
```

But we can still do better! By using `\zs` and `\ze` we can avoid retyping the `src="` bit. `\zs` and `\ze` mark the start and end of the match where the substitution will occur.

```
:%s/\vsrc="\zs(.\{-}\.png)"/<%= image_path("\1") %>"/g
```

However we still are not done because we can take it one step further if we carefully choose where we put `\zs` and `\ze` then we can use vim's `&` in the substitution. It is like `\0` in Perl's regex syntax. Now we don't need any capture groups which nullifies the need for the very magic flag.

```
:%s/src="\zs.\{-}\.png\ze"/<%= image_path("&") %>/g
```

For more help see the following documentation:

```
:h /\zs
:h /\{-
:h s/\&
```

Comment: You seem like a hardcore vim user, Peter, so I have a question: is it worth it to learn vim's (weird?) regexes? I like the editor very much, but it's regex support seems very unnatural, at least to me.

Comment: It is almost always good to learn how to use your editor the best you can. I personally don't find vim's regexs very hard. Short list of tips: 1) learn to love `\zs` 2) don't forget about `[^"]*` patterns 3) Vim has many regex capabilities look at `:h regexp` for more

Answer (score 3):

According to [this website](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern), the syntax for lazy quantifier in vim is different from the syntax used in Perl-like regex.

Let me quote the website:

> ```
>                                                           */\{-*
> \{-n,m}   matches n to m of the preceding atom, as few as possible
> \{-n}     matches n of the preceding atom
> \{-n,}    matches at least n of the preceding atom, as few as possible
> \{-,m}    matches 0 to m of the preceding atom, as few as possible
> \{-}      matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible
>           {Vi does not have any of these}
>
>           n and m are positive decimal numbers or zero
>
>                                                         *non-greedy*
> If a "-" appears immediately after the "{", then a shortest match
> first algorithm is used (see example below).  In particular, "\{-}" is
> the same as "*" but uses the shortest match first algorithm.
> ```

Comment: The command for the less inclined: `:%s/src="\zs.\{-}\.png"/<%= image_path("&") %>/g` or `%s/\vsrc="\zs.{-}\.png"/<%= image_path("&") %>/g` in very magic mode. You may want to look up `:h /\zs` and `:h s/\&`.

Comment: @PeterRincker That was my thought also. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/"\(.*\)"/"<%= image_path("\1") %>"/g`

The double quotes are out main pattern. Everything we want to capture gets thrown into a group `\( \)` so we can later relate to it via `\1`.

---

If you use *very magic*, you have to escape the `=`, thus `\vsrc\=(.*).png"`. So using your way the answer is:

```
:%s/\vsrc\="(.*\.png)"/src="<%= image_path("\1") %>"/g
```

It's easy to see if you `:set hlsearch` and then play around with `/`. :)